# How edit custom option in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Hi i need edit a custom option is a dopdown, [custom option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77fpK.png)

But the problem is I need edit that options in the checkout, but i couldn't get it. I need the code of back.

Comment: Take a look at this table `sales_flat_quote_item_option`